# How to Save NSData to A Location Within my App?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uiimage, nsdata

Hi I'm very new to iOS programming (it's been literally 2 weeks) and I have this issue:

In my app I take pictures and put them in a queue for upload, I still haven't implemented the upload part but I'll upload array of objects(Container) which consist of `NSData` (`UIImageJPEGRepresentation`) but obviously `NSData`s will consume too much memory, so I have to come up with something smarter Instead of holding `NSData` in my Container class I want to hold `NSURL` of the `NSData`. But the `NSData` must be saved somewhere within my app **not** in Camera Roll.

I'm also implementing Core Data to my app and loading `NSData`s will probably take some time.

Here's How My Container class looks like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Container : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * str1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * str2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * bigImageData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * thumbnailData;

@end

@implementation Container

@dynamic str1;
@dynamic str2;
@dynamic bigImageData;
@dynamic thumbnailData;
```

I don't know if it helps but here's how I get the UIImage:

```
UIImage *bigImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,self,nil,nil);

NSData *bigImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(bigImage, 0.1);
//Save NSData to somewhere within my app here
```

So when I start uploading the file, I'll load the NSData back into the memory until the upload is done, then I'll remove the NSData.

I hope I made my problem clear, If you have a better suggestion please let me know,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the data to the `Caches` directory.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cachesFolder = paths[0];
NSString *fullPath = [cachesFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imagename.jpg"];

[bigImageData writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out as soon as I get Core Data working, is there a size limit to Caches directory? the app might end up writing 50mb of data to this directory.

Comment: Yes, there is a limit - the amount of free space left on the iOS device. :) I've written multi-gigabyte files to the Caches directory with no problems.

Comment: Thank you! it works perfectly, but I just have one more question, is there any way to get the image name taken with UIIMagePickerController?
For example when I open Image Capture usually image name is something like IMG_xxx.JPG

Comment: I'm not sure about getting the image's filename. That's a question for another post.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to look for an answer before I post the question, thank you for your help :)